# Read product price from lines - write it to accounting journal - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to read an amount from a `One2many` field, then, depending on the `state` of the record, write off this quantity to a specific journal.

This is my model:

```
class print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'print.order'

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Print Date",default=fields.Datetime.now)
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    due_date = fields.Date(string="Due Date")
    journal_entry = fields.Many2one('account.move', string="Journal Entry")
    stock_picking_id = fields.Many2one('stock.picking', string="Stock Picking")
    order_picking = fields.One2many('print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")
    book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Book Block", default=True, ) 
    binding = fields.Boolean(string="Binding", ) #compute="_bool_binding", readonly=False
    edging = fields.Boolean(string="Edging", ) #compute="_bool_edging", readonly=False
    raw_material_consumed = fields.One2many('stock.move', 'stock_move_lines', string="Raw material consumed")
    contract_worksheet = fields.One2many('mrp.worksheet.contract', 'printer_order', string="Worksheet calculation")
    name_contract = fields.Char(string="Name", compute="_compute_worksheet") 
    state = fields.Selection([
            ('draft','Draft'),
            ('inprogress','In progress'),
            ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
            ('work_in_progress','Print in Progress'),
            ('delivered','Delivered'),
            ('cancel','Cancel'),
        ], string="State")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    printer_book_block = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Book Block")
    printer_binding = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Binding")
    printer_edging = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Edging")
    transporter = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Transporter")
    total_transport_cost = fields.Float(string="Total transport cost")
    additional_job = fields.Boolean(string="Additional Job")
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company',default='_default_company')
    location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string="Source Location")
    location_dest_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string="Destination Location")
```

So, `isbn` is a `Many2one` to `product.product` model, on this model I've created a new `Many2one` field to `account.account`.

As You can see, this class has 'states', so depending on a specific state I should write this quantity from `contract_worksheet` which is a `One2many` field, into the specific journal I've created on `product.product`, on `debit` or `credit` fields.

Now, what confuses me, is how do I access these specific fields on the `One2many`?

And how to automatically do this while changing between states?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@api.model
@api.depends('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn', 'contract_worksheet')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if self.state == awaitingraw:
            self.isbn.printer_wip_account.debit = self.contract_worksheet.total_alles
```

But it doesn't do anything.

So, any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the model which I access from `order_picking` One2many field:

```
class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity") #, compute="_remaining_func"
    is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done", compute="compute_book_block")
    is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done", compute="compute_binding")
    is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done", compute="compute_edging")
    isbns = fields.Many2one('worksheets.isbns', string="Worksheet ISBNS")
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Is accounting_scenarios a method to compute a field? Can you show us how do you define isbn?

I'm not sure, but inside your for loop, you are using "self." instead "record."... I think that may be an issue... It might be necessary to use @api.multi as well...

Comment: Yes, it is a method to compute fields, it should take a field from ´contract_worksheet´ which is a One2many, and copy it to a specific journal, on debit or credit, depending on the case. Gonna edit my question to add the lines.

Comment: Done the editing , Thank You

Comment: What I don't get, is how to achieve this as for example the ´stock_account´ module does, but I think my case is simpler, because I don't need invoices, just print computed quantities into selected journals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `@api.multi`instead of `@api.model`, since you are computing the values.

Also, replace `self` with `record`, like so:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn', 'contract_worksheet')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.state == 'awaitingraw':
            record.isbn.printer_wip_account.debit = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles
```

Comment: Thank You, I've changed it but no effect, what I mean is this behaviour is achieved in other modules silently, I mean, it's not a computed field, that is what I'm struggling to understand, how to achieve this depending on the state, without adding the function to any field, or should I add one even if "invisible" on view?

Comment: Or maybe inheriting the field from journal? But in that case it will be hard coded though :/